# What is the simplest way to handle a case class with a one to many relationship with Slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have the following case class

```
case class News(
                       newsId: Option[Long],
                       name: String,
                       description: String,
                       author: String,
                       creationDateTime: Option[OffsetDateTime],
                       images: Option[List[String]]
               )
```

and would like to use Slick as a database mapping. I was able to create a working DataAccessObject and a `NewsTable` case class **without** the `images: Option[List[String]]`-field.

I dont really know how to approach my problem so i was hoping for a simple guide on how to handle one to many relationships with Slick. (Or does slick support a `List` of `Strings` out of the box)

I guess i should solve this problem with a tupledJoin but i can'tfigure it out.

I think that the given `News` case class violates the slick philosophie "With Slick it is advised to map one table to a tuple or case class without them having object references to related objects." but iam not sure about that. And i dont want to change this model because it is also part of my transfermodel.

Regards :)

Comment: That totally depends on how does your SQL schema look like for `News` and `Image` ?

Comment: Until now i only hat a sql schema for the news because the image was an unknown requirement for me. So iam open for everything :D

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to model this into SQL depending on your requirement, but I am assuming a One-News-To-Many-Images relationship requirement.

Now you can model your SQL tables as follows

```sql
CREATE TABLE news (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  /* ... other properties for news, but nothing for image */

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE images (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  url TEXT NOT NULL
  
  news_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id),

  /* you can decide if you need to a constraint or not */
  FOREIGN KEY (news_id) REFERENCES news(id)
)
```

Now, your slick schema looks like

```scala
case class News(
    id: Int,
    name: String
)

case class Image(
    id: Int,
    url: String,
    newsId: Int
)

class NewsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[News](tag, "news") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")

  def * = (id, name) <> (News.tupled, News.unapply)
}

class ImagesTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Image](tag, "images") {
    def id   = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")

    def newsId = column[Int]("news_id")

    def * = (id, name, newsId) <> (Image.tupled, Image.unapply)
  }

val newsQuery = TableQuery[NewsTable]

val imagesQuery = TableQuery[ImagesTable]
```

Now you can get your news item and images for a `news id = 22` by using following query

```scala
val query =
  newsQuery
    .joinLeft(imagesQuery)
    .on({ case (news, image) => news.id === image.newsId })
    .filter({ case (news, _) => news.id === 22 })

val queryAction = query.result.headOption

val newsOptionFuture = db.run(queryAction)
```

Comment: Thanks for this awesome guid :D 
II'm currently trying to implement your suggestion.

I will probably make your answer the accepted. Therefore i think you made a typo inside `ImagesTable` you have a name column which should probably be a url.

Comment: i think the query has a minor issue. It does not evaluate to a sequence of Images but just one Image

Comment: that is because we are getting only the `headOption` from the result. If you want all tuples then just remove `headOption` from query action.

Comment: hi thx for the fast response. I think you missed my point. I dont want a a `Seq[(NewsDataModel, Option[Image])]` i want a seq of images. Something like this `Seq[(NewsDataModel, Option[Seq[Image]])]`

Comment: You can do that by simply doing a `groupby` on the results. Because a database does not really give you these nested things.